# CompletableFuture does not wait for end previous function in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, completable-future

I have a problem with CompletableFuture. I'm trying to create a modbus (half-duplex) communication module in Spring Boot.

I have a function `startPooling` that `requestForState` every 10s to get a current state and second function `sendSignal` which send signal to eg. change temperature in modbus device. It's a **half-duplex** so `sendSignal` has to wait until `startPooling` (it works on different thread). But my `sendSignal` won't wait until end CompletableFuture from `requestForState` where is a problem?

`requestForState` function looks like:

```java
if (this.updatePending.get()) {
            throw new ModbusBusyException("Cannot request for state device " +getId() + " due to previous request has not end yet");
}
this.setRunningTask(
                    this.getRunningTask()
                            .thenRun(() -> this.updatePending.set(true))
                            .<request-for-state-then-compose-to-state-class>
                            .whenComplete((state,error) -> this.updatePending.set(false)))
return this.getRunningTask().join();
```

`sendSignal` function looks like:

```java
            if(modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().get()){
                LOG.warn("Resync {} is still working ",modbusDevice.getDevice().getId());
                //IT DOES NOT HELP
                modbusDevice.getRunningTask().join();
            }
            modbusDevice.setRunningTask(modbusDevice.getRunningTask()
                    .thenRun(() -> modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().set(true))
                    .thenCompose(voidSignal -> <Comple>)
                    .thenRun(() -> modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().set(false))
                    .thenRun(this.getState(modbusDevice))).join();
```

I created a test example but it works okay:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> System.out.println("STATE"+ modbusDevice.requestForState())).start();

            Thread.sleep(50);

            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - IS THE END OF RESYNC ? " + modbusDevice.getRunningTask().isDone());
                modbusDevice.setRunningTask(
                        modbusDevice.getRunningTask()
                                .thenRun(() -> modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().set(true))
                                .thenRun(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":\t" + LocalDateTime.now() + " - START SENDING EXECUTE"))
                                .thenCompose(voidSignal -> modbusDevice.setFanSpeed(JohnsonControlsFanSpeed.MEDIUM))
                                .thenRun(() -> modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().set(false))
                                .thenRun(() -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":\t" + LocalDateTime.now() + " - STOP SENDING EXECUTE"))
                ).join();
            }).start();

            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too much wishful thinking in this code: `modbusDevice.setRunningTask( modbusDevice.getRunningTask() …)`—what if another `setRunningTask` happens between `getRunningTask()` and the subsequent `setRunningTask(…)`? `modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().get()`—what if this test is executed right *before* the other thread does `modbusDevice.getUpdatePending().set(true)`? Of course, an artificial test with threads slowed down to never overlap will not reproduce such problems.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I know it looks a bit messy. I created a full-duplex (non-blocking) connection and it works fine. So I wanted to use the same scheme with half-duplex. How should it look like? I need use CompletableFuture due to compatybility with full-duplex. Maybe Queue or ReactorProject Sink?

Comment: You need a real atomic update for the RunningTask property. Then, replace the boolean UpdatePending flag with either a mutex or a semaphore. A `Phaser` based solution could also work. A boolean flag can only work if you integrate it into the atomic update of RunningTask, i.e. the flag has to be true already when the new task has been set.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! So I have to read more about that, I thought I would solve it in some simpler way :)

Comment: @Holger Thank you so much! Mutex is useful, now works as it should

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger), I was able to fix my problem.

First of all, for some reason (I was using Mono/Flux a lot) I didn't think that CompletableFuture is called immediately on creation and not, as in Mono, only after subscription. Because of which, even after using Mutex, I had a problem with overlapping signals. Only after converting CompletableFuture to Supplier did I get what I wanted.

```java
public class Synchronous {
    private final Lock mutex = new ReentrantLock();

    public <T> T runTask(Supplier<CompletableFuture<T>> task) {
        T response = null;
        Exception catchedException = null;
        try {
                mutex.lock();
                response = task.get().join();
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                catchedException = exception;
            } finally {
                mutex.unlock();
            }
        if(catchedException != null){
            throw new RuntimeException(catchedException);
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```